# Swift: Capture inout parameter in closures that escape the called function

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I tried to write an "editor" class that could retain a reference to a property on a different object for later mutation.  I first wrote the editor class to receive a closure for reading, and a closure for writing.  This worked.  I then tried to pass the parameter in question by (inout) reference, and then generate the getter / setter pair from that.  This did not work.  The Swift docs does say (paraphrasing) that Swift figures out when to copy, and when to not.  I think I am up against unpredictability of that limitation, but thought I'd pose the question just the same.

Alternatively, is it possible to get a curried function for the individual getter and setter?

My code is:

```
class SomeModel : Printable {

    var a:String

    init(a:String) {
        self.a = a
    }

    var description:String {
        return "\(self.a)"
    }
}


class Editor {

    var getter:()-> String
    var setter:(String)->()

    init(getter:()-> String, setter:(String)->()) {
        self.getter = getter
        self.setter = setter
    }

    convenience init(inout bindTo:String) {
        self.init(
            getter:{ return bindTo },
            setter: { v in bindTo = v })
    }

    func read() -> String {
        return self.getter()
    }

    func write(value:String) {
        self.setter(value)
    }
}


func testBindTo() {
    var readModel =  SomeModel(a:"Did not capture by reference");
    var bindForReading = Editor(bindTo: &readModel.a)
    readModel.a = "captured by reference!"
    println(bindForReading.read())

    var writeModel =  SomeModel(a:"Did not capture by reference");
    var bindForWriting = Editor(bindTo: &writeModel.a)
    bindForWriting.write("captured by reference")
    println(writeModel)
}

testBindTo()


func testExplicitGetterSetter() {

    var readModel =  SomeModel(a:"Did not capture by reference");
    var bindForReading = Editor(
        getter: { readModel.a },
        setter: { v in readModel.a = v })
    readModel.a = "captured by reference!"
    println(bindForReading.read())

    var writeModel =  SomeModel(a:"Did not capture by reference");
    var bindForWriting = Editor(
        getter: { writeModel.a },
        setter: { v in writeModel.a = v })
    bindForWriting.write("captured by reference")
    println(writeModel)     
}

testExplicitGetterSetter()
```

The results are:

```
Did not capture by reference
Did not capture by reference
captured by reference!
captured by reference
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is possible. And it *shouldn't* be possible, if you think about it, because it would be super unsafe.

Because closures can outlive the scope they were created in, captured variables must be stored with the block. But in order to be able to assign to the captured variable and share the state of that variable between the (one or more) block(s) that captured it and the original scope, the blocks cannot just capture the value of the variable (which would create independent copies of the variable), but capture a kind of "reference" to a shared copy. This means that assignable variables that are captured by blocks must be stored specially. In Objective-C, this is declared with `__block`. In Swift, this `__block` behavior is implicit.

However, in order for the block to modify an `inout` variable (potentially at a later time) as it is seen in the function caller's scope, that would mean that the passed variable in the caller's scope would also need to be stored in a way that can outlive the stack frame. But the caller function doesn't know this. All it knows from the type of the called function is that one of its parameters is `inout`; it doesn't know that the function plans to capture that `inout` variable in a block. So it doesn't know to prepare this `__block` storage for this passed variable.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, it seems like there are two issues: closure copy semantics, and object lifetime.  To the latter point, you can already create a class (reference type) on the stack and call a function that stores it beyond the lifetime of the function.  To the first point though, Swift's automatic copy semantics handling seems to take care of the _block issue, they just don't play together.  What I really want is to get the curried getter / setter.  Hopefully they add syntax for that at some point.  Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @chrisco: This is not about "objects" (which are pointed to by variables of reference types), but *variables* themselves (either variables of value type or reference type; it doesn't matter). A *local variable*, no matter in Objective-C or Swift, only has lifetime of the scope in which it was declared, unless it's declared `__block` in Objective-C or used in a closure in Swift, in which case the compiler stores it in a way that it can live longer.

Comment: @newacct your explanation seems to have a hole in it, because __block is only required on values that will be mutated.  Other values are captured without a special annotation and out-live their stack frames with no problem.  In general, what you said seems to make a lot of sense however.  My issue is, this functionality is needed.  There should be a swift keyword to enable these values to be properly stored so they can be mutated in this way.

Comment: @BTRUE: My description was indeed incorrect; I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follows.  )Notice that the closure and the inout param have the same lifespan.)

```
/// A class providing access to a resource with an inout parameter in an escaping closure.   
     class ProtectedResource<ValueType> {
            private var protectedResourceArray = [ValueType]()
            private var protectedResourceArrayLock = NSRecursiveLock()
            private let opq = OperationQueue()

            func performWithResource(block: @escaping (inout [ValueType]) -> ()) {
                opq.addOperation { [weak self] in
                    guard let strongSelf = self else {
                        return
                    }
                    strongSelf.protectedResourceArrayLock.lock()
                    block(&strongSelf.protectedResourceArray)
                    strongSelf.protectedResourceArrayLock.unlock()
                }
            }
        }

/// Some other class using that in out parameter. 

        func run() {

            func updateArray(array: inout [String]) {
                print("Performing on \(array)")
                array.append("test")
            }

            protectedResource.performWithResource(block: updateArray)

            protectedResource.performWithResource {
                print("Performing on \($0)")
            }
    }
```